# Python cannot import pmdarima ARIMA function

Tags: python, github, ipython, spyder

I have installed the lib pmdarima with the instruction from the [GitHub page](https://github.com/tgsmith61591/pmdarima). But when I imported the auto_arima function, it gives the errors below:

```
     [1] from pmdarima.arima import auto_arima

    Traceback (most recent call last):

    File "<ipython-input-12-6858fadc5169>", line 1, in <module>
        from pmdarima.arima import auto_arima

      File "C:\Users\WIN\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pmdarima\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
        from .arima import auto_arima, ARIMA

      File "C:\Users\WIN\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pmdarima\arima\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
        from .approx import *

      File "C:\Users\WIN\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pmdarima\arima\approx.py", line 19, in <module>
        from pmdarima.arima._arima import C_Approx

      File "__init__.pxd", line 918, in init pmdarima.arima._arima

    ValueError: numpy.ufunc size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 216 from C header, got 192 from PyObject
```

How should I resolve the problem?

Comment: I think you corrupted your Anaconda installation. So my recommendation is to reinstall it, then create a new conda environment (please google how to do it) and finally install that library in the previous environment.

Comment: Why to create a new conda env before reinstall the package?

Comment: Because pip and conda packages are not binary compatible, so you can't mix them.

Comment: If you're still having the same problem, I would try to upgrade your `numpy` library. What's your library version? Check [this issue[(https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/hdbscan/issues/272)

Comment: @CarlosCordoba: What do you mean by corrupted Anaconda installation? You can use both tools (`conda` and `pip`) together. Of course some issues can rise up, but for `pmdarima` lib you don't have other choice (if you don't want to build it from source). But agree, you should be careful about that (https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/)

Comment: You only can use pip in Anaconda to install pure Python packages that don't install compiled packages (such as Numpy). Other than that, using pip will certainly break your Anaconda installation.

Answer (score -1):

Reinstall numpy
`pip install numpy` And install 
`pip install pmdarima`. It will work!

Comment: If you're using Anaconda, as it's clear from the traceback above, this is the worst possible advice. That's because pip and conda packages are binary incompatible, so using pip to install numpy will corrupt your Anaconda installation.